# Get python typing.Type from name str

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm using the `__annotations__` object to get a dict of class member names and their objects in a Python class like this one:

```
class Test(Model):
    foo: int = 0
    bar: str = "hi"
```

The value of `__annotations__` is correct:

```
{'foo': 'int', 'bar': 'str'}
```

However, I have been unsuccessful in trying to find a way to get a `typing.Type` object from the name. I tried using the `pydoc.locate` module but it always returned `None`.

I need this to work with builtins and imported modules.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer myself:

Due to the fact that I imported `__future__.annotations` (because I tested something different), all type hints were turned into strings. As soon as I removed the import it worked.

Comment: more information: using `ForwardRef` it is actually possible to resolve these string type hints to actually `typing.Type`s.